# Include belongsTo and hasMany to builder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I include the region and category language of category table in the builder. The region returns the exact output that I want, but the category language always returns empty. I copy the query and run it to Postgres and it returns some data.

---

**Query**

[image]

**Relation of region and category language to category table**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

**Category Language Schema**

[image]

**Executed query for Category Language Table in Postgres. Working fine here**

[image]

**CategoryLanguageRegion Model**

[image]

Comment: Please share your category languages table schema

Comment: @EmtiazZahid, I added it. Please check. Thank you

Comment: try to mention foreign key and owner key while you setting the relationship methods in your model.

Comment: @EmtiazZahid, I also added the executed query for category language in Postgres

Comment: Can you show your `CategoryLanguageRegion` model?

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal, Ok. I added it. Please check. Thank you

Comment: mention foreign key in your relationship : public function categoryLanguages()
{
 return $this->hasMany('App\CategoryLanguageRegion', 'category_id');
}

Comment: @EmtiazZahid, Still returning empty.

Comment: use like this `public function categoryLanguages() { return $this->hasMany('App\CategoryLanguageRegion', 'category_id','id'); }`

Comment: what it returns when you use                                                                         
         $results = Category::with(['region', 'categoryLanguages'])->get(); ?

Comment: @EmtiazZahid, It is working fine now. I think there is a problem when I use this code "'categoryLanguages' => function($query){ $query->select('id', 'title', 'description', 'language_id'); }". I don't why. but anyways, thank you.

Comment: @testhill, one more thing, from next time onwards if you face any issue, please try to post the code instead of an image, because it really helps us a lot.

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal, okay understand. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add `category_id` in `select` query as follows:

```
'categoryLanguages' => functon($query) { 
   $query->select('id', 'title', 'description', 'category_id');
}
```

For `region`, you don't have to add because mapping is other way around. It's `Category` model that contains foreign key `region_id`, but for `CategoryLanguage`, `Category` model doesn't have any foreign key that's why you have to explicitly add `category_id` in select query.

Comment: Solved my problem and learned to always add the foreign key when selecting data on the sub table. Thank you very much @Prashant Pokhriyal